# After training set are normalized what should test set do

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, data-science

the training set head looks this way

```
    Session ID  Timestamp               Item ID     Price   Quantity
0   420374  2014-04-06T18:44:58.314Z    214537888   12462   1
1   420374  2014-04-06T18:44:58.325Z    214537850   10471   1
2   281626  2014-04-06T09:40:13.032Z    214535653   1883    1
3   420368  2014-04-04T06:13:28.848Z    214530572   6073    1
4   420368  2014-04-04T06:13:28.858Z    214835025   2617    1
```

So I preprocess the data,make them normalized column by column and fit them to SGDClassifier.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp

scaler = pp.MinMaxScaler()
columns_list = list(train_data.columns)
del columns_list[-1]
train_data[columns_list] = scaler.fit_transform(train_data[columns_list])

clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data.iloc[:, :-2],train_data.iloc[:,-1])
```

Then I want to predict with the model,like `clf.predict()` but the origin test set are supposed to be the following format.

```
    Session ID  Timestamp               Item ID     Price   Quantity
0   420374  2014-04-06T18:44:58.314Z    214537888   12462   1
```

Then do I need to make them to normalize with the training set also?

What test data do the model expecting?

What prepocessing do the test data need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We apply all the preprocessing to test data which was learnt when performed on train data. We don't learn anything new from test data.

So in your case, we only apply the same normalizing to test data which we learnt from train data:-

```
test_data[columns_list] = scaler.transform(test_data[columns_list])

# Predict Quantity from model
y_pred = clf.predict(test_data.iloc[:, :-2])

# Actual values of Quantity
y_true = test_data.iloc[:,-1]

# Now use y_true and y_pred to calculate the metrics.
```

Answer (score 0):

[As sklearn doc provide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling)

> The preprocessing module further provides a utility class
>   StandardScaler that implements the Transformer API to compute the mean
>   and standard deviation on a training set so as to be able to later
>   reapply the same transformation on the testing set.

[Talk about the Normalizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization)

> The preprocessing module further provides a utility class Normalizer
>   that implements the same operation using the Transformer API

so just reapply the same transformation on the testing set would be fine.